# $ is used before defined bootstrap Jquery

Tags: javascript

I was just following the tutorial at linda.com and faced problem
I have index bootstrap.js and are being used in different folder 
I think this is file location problem....or not.

I attached a photo of my project 
structure

[image: my folder structure is like below]

and my index code is like this

```html
<!doctype>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Happy Card---Home</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-US-Compatible" content="Chrome">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/myscript.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
     
     
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy|Covered+By+Your+Grace|Dancing+Script|Graduate|Great+Vibes|Orbitron|Oswald|Permanent+Marker|Saira+Extra+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
     
     
 </head>
 
 <body id="Home">
  <section class="container"> 
    <?php include "_/component/php/header.php"?>
   <div class="content row">
    <section class="main col col-lg-8">
     
    </section><!---main--->
    <section class="sidebar col col-lg-4">
     
    </section><!---sidebar--->
   </div><!---content--->
  </section><!---container--->
  
       
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="js/myscript.js"></script>
  
 </body>
```

```js
$(function(){
 
    $('ul.nav il.dropdown').hover(function(){
   $('.dropdown-menu',this).fadeIn();  
    }, function(){
    $('.dropdown-menu',this).fadeout('fast');
   });
   });
```

```html
<!doctype>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Happy Card---Home</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-US-Compatible" content="Chrome">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-
    scale=1.0">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="js/myscript.js">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" media="screen">
     

     
     
 </head>
 
 <body id="Home">
  <section class="container"> 
    <?php include "_/component/php/header.php"?>
   <div class="content row">
    <section class="main col col-lg-8">
     
    </section><!---main--->
    <section class="sidebar col col-lg-4">
     
    </section><!---sidebar--->
   </div><!---content--->
  </section><!---container--->
  
       
  <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="js/myscript.js"></script>
  
 </body>
 <footer>
    

 </footer>
</html>
```

And header is like this

```html
<div class="content row">
 <div class="col-lg-12">
  <header class="clearfix">
   <section id="branding">
    <a href="index.php"></a>
   </section><!---branding--> 
    
   <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
     <div class="container-fluid">
     <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile 
display -->
     <div class="navbar-header">
       <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" 
data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-
expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
       <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Batam Tour &amp; 
Living Info</a>
     </div>

     <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for 
toggling -->
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-
navbar-collapse-1">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)
   </span></a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
     
        <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-
toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-
expanded="false">Batam Tour <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">ATTRACTION</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">SHOPPING MALL</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">THINGS TO DO</a></li>
       <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
       <li><a href="#">RENT CAR</a></li>
       <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
       <li><a href="#">HAPPY CARD</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-
toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-
expanded="false">Living Info <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">REAL ESTATE</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">BUSINESS ENVIRONMENT</a></li>
       <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
       <li><a href="#">BUSINESS CONSULTING</a></li>
       <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
       <li><a href="#">LIVING Q&amp;A</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
                 
       </ul>
       <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" 
placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-
default">Submit</button>
       </form>
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
      
       </ul>
     </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    
  </header><!---header-->
 </div><!---column-->
</div><!---content-->
```

Comment: I think problem area is `<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/myscript.js">` test once with removing it

Comment: Two typos. I vote to close _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting._

Comment: @SonnyCho - please delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have two typos

`il` instead of `li` and `fadeout` instead of `fadeOut` and you unnecessary load myscript.js as a `<link rel="stylesheet"`  - you can remove that line

If I add the JS and CSS and insert your header it works:

---

```
$(function() {
  $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).fadeIn();
  }, function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).fadeOut('fast');
  });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).fadeIn();
  }, function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu', this).fadeOut('fast');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Chewy|Covered+By+Your+Grace|Dancing+Script|Graduate|Great+Vibes|Orbitron|Oswald|Permanent+Marker|Saira+Extra+Condensed" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<section class="container">

  <div class="content row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <header class="clearfix">
        <section id="branding">
          <a href="index.php"></a>
        </section>
        <!---branding-->

        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile 
display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria- expanded="false">
      <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Batam Tour &amp; 
Living Info</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for 
toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-
navbar-collapse-1">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)
   </span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data- toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria- expanded="false">Batam Tour <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">ATTRACTION</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">SHOPPING MALL</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">THINGS TO DO</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">RENT CAR</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">HAPPY CARD</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data- toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria- expanded="false">Living Info <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">REAL ESTATE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BUSINESS ENVIRONMENT</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">BUSINESS CONSULTING</a></li>
                    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LIVING Q&amp;A</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>

              </ul>
              <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-
default">Submit</button>
              </form>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>

              </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>

      </header>
      <!---header-->
    </div>
    <!---column-->
  </div>
  <!---content-->

  <div class="content row">
    <section class="main col col-lg-8">

    </section>
    <!---main--->
    <section class="sidebar col col-lg-4">

    </section>
    <!---sidebar--->
  </div>
  <!---content--->
</section>
<!---container--->
```

Comment: oh.........simple but caused critical errro...........Resolved SIR~!!!! ^^; Thank you mplungjan!!!